# React Routing no funciona en una app dentro de un dominio con Wordpress

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, react-router-dom

Tengo un blog en Wordpress y de manera independiente he desarrollado una app en React en un subdirectorio. La app funciona, se carga correctamente, pero cuando uso algún path me da dos tipos de error según configure htaccess por lo que he podido investigar pero sigo sin poder hacer que funcione:

**htaccess versión 1:** Aparece error 404 del theme instalado en dominio.com

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**htaccess versión 2:** Error 404 del servidor

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(app|app/.*)$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**En React:**

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

<BrowserRouter basename="/app">
 <Routes>
<Route exact path="/seccion/subseccion/" element={<Component />} />
```

**Resultado actual:**

1. Blog: dominio.com
2. App React: dominio.com/app (Funciona)
3. App React con Routing: dominio.com/app/seccion/subseccion/ (No funciona)

En localhost si se carga correctamente.

1. App React: localhost.3000/app (Funciona)
2. App React con Routing: localhost.3000/app/seccion/subseccion/ (Funciona)

¿Alguien puede orientarme que mas hacer?